# TYPO3 typoscript set includeCSS trough userFunc

Tags: class, typo3, typoscript

I have a site that has a dark theme and light theme set in function of the daylight ...
in my constants i define `sunset` and `sunrise` and I have a Class that I reach through `userFunc`, my class:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Utility;

use TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer;

/**
 * will return theme class in various instances of the page
 */

class ThemeClass extends ContentObjectRenderer
{
    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer
     */
    public $cObj;

    /**
     * Returns theme class according to daylight
     *
     * @var string $content
     * @var array $config
     * @return string
     **/
    protected function class($content, array $config = null)
    {
        // init
        $sunRise = $this->cObj->stdWrapValue('sunRise', $config, null);
        $sunSet = $this->cObj->stdWrapValue('sunSet', $config, null);
        $format = 'h:i a';
    
        $now = date_create_from_format($format, Date($format));
        $open = date_create_from_format($format, $sunRise);
        $close = date_create_from_format($format, $sunSet);
    
        return $theme = ($now > $open && $now < $close) ? 'light' : 'dark' ;
    }

    /**
     * Returns body tag according to theme
     *
     * @var string $content
     * @var array $config
     * @return string
     **/
    public function bodyTag($content, array $config = null)
    {
        $theme = $this->class($content, $config);

        return '<body class="'.$theme.'">';
    }

    /**
     * Returns css according to theme
     *
     * @var string $content
     * @var array $config
     * @return string
     **/
    public function themeCss($content, array $config = null)
    {
        $theme = $this->class($content, $config);

        return 'EXT:extension/Resources/Public/Css/_'.$theme.'.css">';
    }

}
```

I use the theme overrideing the bodytag like this:

```
page.bodyTag >
page.bodyTagCObject = USER
page.bodyTagCObject {
    userFunc = Vendor\Extension\Utility\ThemeClass->bodyTag
    sunRise = {$extension.config.daylight.sunrise}
    sunSet = {$extension.config.daylight.sunset}
}
```

I expected that something similar would work here :

```
page.includeCSS {
    theme.cObject = USER
    theme.cObject {
        userFunc = Vendor\Extension\Utility\ThemeClass->themeCss
        sunRise = {$extension.config.daylight.sunrise}
        sunSet = {$extension.config.daylight.sunset}
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work within `includeCSS` ... I tried a few 'side-steps' of this but cannot get anything to work ...

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a good error message. Please give more information what is currently working and what not.

Comment: Although `includeCSS` has no stdWrap functionality, you can't use a `cObject` inside there: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Setup/Page/Index.html#includecss-array

Comment: Which TYPO3 version do you use?

Comment: @ThomasLöffler thanks for the attention, the bodytag snippet does work, the includeCSS does not include the intented css file ... I work with V11.5.13

Comment: @ThomasLöffler I tried it as a temp.variable and then read it in ... includeCSS.thema < temp.themeCss but that does not go either ... I thought about setting a global variable 'theme' and override page.includeCSS.thema with a condition if dark, but I didn't get how to do that

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use a temp object or directly in includeCSS. It won't work. What about using JS for handling the different CSS themes? See: https://fjolt.com/article/css-auto-dark-mode

Comment: @ThomasLöffler rather no js... rather keep the logic together in the class

Answer (score 0):

You *could* register a `USER` or `USER_INT` somewhere in the `page` object and in you user function get the `AssetCollector` to register CSS.

Comment: your reputation shows you'r an expert ... i wouldn't know where to take your suggestion without some snippet, i'm just not good enough a scripter, at least of the ```AssetCollector``` ... in the meantime are going to try to do something with your info